# Selfie stick button causes music to play instead of taking photo

Tags: camera, volume-control

I am trying to get a selfie stick to work with a HTC One X running CyanogenMod 7.

The selfie stick is button activated with a 3.5mm "headphone" jack.
http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B010QPQDRC

The default camera app on the phone takes photos when pressing the volume down button.

However, when I use the selfie stick button, it starts up the music app and begins to play music (almost as if it is sending the play/pause signal instead of volume down).

I tried the selfie stick with a Nexus 5 running stock Lollipop and it works perfectly fine using Google Camera.

I have tried disabling the music app (Apollo) but that did not work.

Any ideas welcome!